# How to return an array of random keys?

Tags: php, loops

Let me ask you how to return any three random numbers into the array that is different from the other numbers in the array.

```
$checkrandom=array(1,2,3,4);
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    $random=RAND(1,10);
    if(!in_array($random,$checkrandom)){
        array_push($checkrandom,$random);
    }else{
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what would be expected at the end ? And explain a bit more, I'm afraid I didn't get it all

Comment: I would say that the easiest solution would be to turn `for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){` into `while($i<3)`. It's not very clear what are you trying to do. And why are you trying to do it with `rand()`

Comment: You need to state clearly what you want so that help can be provided

Comment: why don't you shuffle($checkrandom) your data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than guess numbers and add them if they don't already exist, this creates an array of the remaining numbers (using a combination of `range()` and `array_diff()`).  It then picks numbers out of that array (using `shuffle()` and `array_shift()`) and adds them to the end of `$checkrandom`.

```
$checkrandom=array(1,2,3,4);
$numbers = array_diff(range(1,10), $checkrandom);
for($i=0;$i<3;$i++){
    shuffle($numbers);
    $checkrandom[]=array_shift($numbers);
}
print_r($checkrandom);
```

Or, as deceze pointed out, just shuffle the remaining array and use `array_slice()` to extract the first 3 numbers...

```
$checkrandom=array(1,2,3,4);
$numbers = array_diff(range(1,10), $checkrandom);
shuffle($numbers);
$checkrandom = array_merge($checkrandom, array_slice($numbers, 0, 3));
print_r($checkrandom);
```

Comment: You really just need to shuffle once and take three.